# Jquery Validation Date Picker

Tags: jquery, validation, datepicker

I'm working on this site:

I am using Jquery calender plugin along with Tabs and Jquery Validation.js.

It works all smoothly, but if you click on the second tab over on the top it shows the calender from the first page. For an example click `2.Promotion`.

As `Start_date` is mandatory Validation.js highlights the Start_date causing calender to pop up.

I have tried but wasn't able to stop this from happening. Can you suggest a way to solve this?

You can view the site [here](http://www.redflowermedia.com/contest/ContestWizard.php).

Badly struck

Answer (score 0):

Quick fix;

hide the date picker when tab 2 is clicked;

i.e on click of tab2:

```
document.getElementById("ui-datepicker-div").style.display='none';
```

Comment: i donot think this will work fieldset isnot clickable.... it is made clickable at run time